# ProviderCollection To Dictionary

Tags: c#, design-patterns, collections

I've implemented the provider pattern and created a providercollection that I'm using in my project.
I need to implement a search against a property in the list of providers I have for a certain value. I was wondering is there a way to convert the providercollection to a dictionary in an elegant way? With the dictionary I can use find to match value. Looking for a Dictionary or maybe there is a better way to handle this kind of scenario instead of doing a basic foreach loop. All help and greatly appreciated. An Ex. would be helpful.

Thanks,
DND

Is there a better, cleaner way to write this search code??? I was thinking of using a dictionary like John has shown me below. What do you think?

```
var ProdNumVal = from p in xdoc.Root.Element("ClientOrderId").Elements()
                         where (string)p.Attribute("name") == "ProductNumber"
                         select (string)p.Value;


        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProdNumVal.ToString()))
        {
            foreach (XMLProviderBase prov in Providers)
            {
                products = prov.ProductNumber.Split(';');
                foreach (string prod in products)
                {
                    if (prod == ProdNumVal.FirstOrDefault())
                        return prov;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about `System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderCollection` or is this your own Provider collection class?

In any case, your ProviderCollection is an IEnumerable, you can use the LINQ ToDictionary() method to generate the dictionary:

```
        ProviderCollection pc = <initialize somehow>;
        Dictionary<string, string> d = pc
            .Cast<ProviderBase>()
            .ToDictionary(pb => pb.Name, pb => pb.Description);
```

The first arg to ToDictionary() selects the key, the 2nd arg selects the value.  Here, I'm just grabbing Name/Description for an example (assuming ProviderBase is the element type), but you can pick whatever values you need.

Hope that helps,

John

Comment: John - you are correct in your assumption, I am using providercollection in provider pattern. Your code to create a dictionary is what I was looking for, thanks. See ultimately I'm trying to do a search on providerscollection which is a generic collection and doesn't have a find method. I have written this code to get back what I want but it is ugly, what do you think? how would you do it differently?  See code added to orig post. - DND

Comment: Hi -- now I think I understand what you're looking for a bit better, and I'm not sure a Dictionary is really what you want.  I can help a bit more if you can  do a couple things: 1) post a bit of sample XML 2) post the definition of XMLProviderBase and Providers.